# Не отображаются изменения после правок на сервере

Tags: css, wordpress

Заменяю файлы сайта на сервере, вношу изменения в css, но они не отображаются на страницах, сайт на вордпресс.

Comment: Кэширование. Ctrl+F5 в браузере.

Comment: или в хроме ctrl+shift+r

Comment: @kizoso ctrl+F5 тоже в Хроме

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего стоит плагин для кеширования страницы на wordpress надо бы его отключить + так же сбросить кеш в wordpress. В интернете есть инфа о том как сбросить кеш на wordpress. Т.е. скорее всего у Вам проблема не с браузером, а с самим wordpress